# grep lines with X but not with Y

Tags: linux, grep, include

The problem:

I want to get all lines of code in my project folder that have ".js" in order to check that i don't have un-minimized JavaScript files.

When I'm trying to do the following: grep -H ".js\"" * 
I'm getting everything right. but still have a problem as I don't want to get lines with ".min.js" which i don't want to get.

Is it possible using grep command to search my project folder for all files/lines that have ".js" but not ".min.js" ?

Thanks.
GalT.

Comment: Is that you just need to search particular folder or all the folders within project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pipe the output to another `grep` as

```
grep -H ".js" | grep -vH ".min.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command will work in folder as well.

For current dir you can use this

```
find . | xargs grep  ".js" | grep -v "min.js"
```

For any specific folder

```
find (folder path) | xargs grep  ".js" | grep -v "min.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `awk`

```
awk '/.js/ && !/.min.js/'
```

To print filename:

```
awk '/.js/ && !/.min.js/ {print FILENAME}' *
```